# Cordova: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Ни с того ни с сего стала появляться эта ошибка. Недавно обновлял nodejs (четыре дня назад), снес всё, в том числе кордову. Но после установки заново всё работало. Я пилил потихоньку js, как вдруг приложение перестало стартовать:

> 02-02 13:45:19.192: I/Web Console(18633): deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1185
>   02-02 13:58:38.941: I/Web Console(18841): Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1178

Я сразу все привел к виду "почти как helloworld", но ошибка не исчезла.
Так же не помогло
**cordova platform remove android**
**cordova platform add anodroid**
и удаление приложения с телефона

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.dict_app" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name></name>
    <description>
    </description>
    <icon src="www/img/logo.png" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-websql" version="0.0.9" />
    <preference name="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE"/>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" />
        <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="false"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <script>
             //Тут пара вспомогательных функций
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- тут вёрстка -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready',
function(){
   console.log('Ready');
},
//app.init,
false);
```

Comment: Попробуйте подключиться через Chrome к устройству, и нажать Ctrl + R чтобы обновить приложение на телефоне, возможно вы увидите ту ошибку, которая помешала вызову события DeviceReady. Также посмотрите на вкладку Network, возможно у вас какие то зависимости не грузятся